# CRM dynamic "an error occurred when verifying security for the message"

Tags: php, web-services, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I am tring to access http://xxxxxxxxxxx/CRM2011/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl

I can able to see functions list. means i can access to webservice. But while i tring to write data using function create it through "an error occurred when verifying security for the message" my code is below

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$location = "http://182.18.175.29/CRM2011/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl";
$config['Username'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['Password'] = 'xxxxxx';
$config['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_2;
$config['trace'] = 1; // enable trace to view what is happening
$config['use'] = SOAP_LITERAL;
$config['style'] = SOAP_DOCUMENT;
$config['exceptions'] = 0; // disable exceptions
$config["cache_wsdl"] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE; // disable any caching on the wsdl, encase you alter the wsdl server
$config["features"] = SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS;

include_once 'ntlmSoap.php';
$client = new NTLMSoapClient($location, $config);
print('<pre>');
print_r($client->__getFunctions());

$HeaderSecurity = array("UsernameToken" => array("Username" => 'xxxxxx', "Password" => 'xxxxxx'));
$header[] = new SoapHeader($location, "Security", $HeaderSecurity);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);


$params = array(
    "bmw_firstname" => "test",
    "bmw_lastname" => "test"
);

try {
    $response = $client->__soapCall("Create", $params);
    var_dump($response);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}

// display what was sent to the server (the request)
echo "<p>Request :" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . "</p>";
// display the response from the server
echo "<p>Response:" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()) . "</p>";
```

Comment: I think its NOT a good idea to put your live IP addresses in public forum.

Comment: You're not really accessing the webservice - you're only requesting the webservice description which doesn't require authentication. I don't have any experience in accessing the OrganizationService from PHP but I'd check if your IIS is configured to allow NTLM authentication which I assume is what you're using.

Comment: I have anonymised your IP address. Its not safe to share IP address to public. I would recommend you not to share your ID address with anyone.